# Averaging Across All Matrices Stored in Structure

Tags: matlab, matrix, structure

I am currently using the following code to get an average across 8766 matrices stored in a structure, `matData`, but when I look inside `Mcell` (1x8766 cell) all of the values stored in each cell are duplicates of that in cell 1x1. I would like to know what I am doing wrong, since I will then take the `nanmean` of all the matrices in this structure.

```
Mcell = arrayfun(@(x) matData(sprintf('(%d)',x)).shape, 1:8766, 'uni', 0);
M = nanmean( reshape(cell2mat(Mcell), 192, 144, []), 3 );
```

Extra notes: `matData` is 1x8766 struct with 1 field files in `matdata` are called `matData(i).shape` where `i=1:8766` and are 192x144 double.

Thank you for all of your input and help.

Comment: Isn't the first line same as `Mcell = arrayfun(@(x)x.shape,matData,'uni',0)` ? Seems like a roundabout way of doing things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a combination of `struct2cell`, `cell2mat` and `nanmean`:

```
matData = cell2struct(num2cell(randn(192,144,8766),[1,2]), 'shape', 1); % Sample input

result = nanmean(cell2mat(struct2cell(matData)),3);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try your way as well. I went ahead and did this and it worked: 'lflocrcp45= struct2cell(matData);
              matlfrcp45=cell2mat(lflocrcp45);'

Comment: Well, that's exactly what my answer says.. and additional `nanmean` call